How to make a first class function cell in Excel
It is possible in excel to treat a cell akin to a first-class function?
For example, the typical behavior would be to set cell C1's value to =A1+B1 which is an immediate execution function. The function is abstracted away from view.
Instead, I would like to set C1 to something like = FUNC(arg1,arg2) => arg1+arg2 then set D1 to = C1(A1,B1) such that the function contained in C1 is always visible. The cell C1 is a function itself, not a data point, and does not evaluate to anything.
The basic functionality of Excel is that cells are values, even with functions, since functions are immediately executed to a value.
I'm asking if there's a higher order.
I noticed the LAMBDA function but it's not higher order.

No, a cell cannot contain a function that can be called from another cell.  LAMBDA in the Name Manager can.  There may also be a way through VBA.  But not through the native cell itself.

I think that there is a way to evaluate  text strings ... I don't  have access to my PC right now to check

@jsotola not without the name manager or vba.  And if you are going to use the Name Manager it is a deprecated function and Lamda would work better, as you would need to nest SUBSTITUTE to change the place holders with the correct values before passing the string to the function stored in the name manager.
